# Convert from window name to shell?

Tags: shell, x11, motif

Using a combination of `XInterAtom(disp, "_NET_CLIENT_LIST", False)` and `XGetWindowProperty`, I can successfully obtain a list of running windows.

However, is there a way to convert that data to a pointer to a shell or widget, to be able to determine when a given window is closed, or what it's children are, or to create any callbacks?

I have tried to use `XtWindowToWidget` and `XtHooksOfDisplay` to no avail, but I could have been using them incorrectly as well.

Or, is there another way to do this... knowing that the shell and window creation is part of a different application that I cannot modify?